# Where does this inequality in a paper come from?

Tags: inequality

It's probably simple but I'm not sure why I'm not seeing it. The inequality is from a paper:

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^4 \rho_i (x_i-1)(1-\sum_{j=1}^4 \alpha_{ij}x_j) &\leq\begin{split}
&\mathbin{\hphantom{+}}x_1(2\rho_1 + \rho_2\alpha_{21}+ \rho_3\alpha_{31}+\rho_4\alpha_{41}) \\&+x_2(\rho_1\alpha_{12} + 2\rho_2+ \rho_3\alpha_{32}+\rho_4\alpha_{42}) \\&+ x_3(\rho_1\alpha_{13} + \rho_2\alpha_{23}+ 2\rho_3+\rho_4\alpha_{43}) \\&+ x_4(\rho_1\alpha_{14} + \rho_2\alpha_{24} + 2\rho_3\alpha_{34}+2\rho_4)
\end{split}
\end{align*}$$

Here, $\rho_i > 0, x_i(t) > 0$, and $\alpha_{ij} > 0$ for all $i$ and $j$.

I would think that since $x_i - 1 < x_i$ and $1-\sum_{j=1}^4 \alpha_{ij}x_j < 1$, I could just get the inequality:

$$\sum_{i=1}^4 \rho_i (x_i-1)(1-\sum_{j=1}^4 \alpha_{ij}x_j) \leq \sum_{i=1}^4 \rho_i x_i$$. Clearly if this inequality is true, so is the one from the paper, but then I'm not sure why they used so much more complicated bound with $2$'s in random places.

Comment: Those places don't look random.

Comment: @Théophile It didn't to me either until the $x_4$ line has two $2's$ while the others only have one, which I can't imagine a reason for

Comment: What perplexes me is the second to last $2$, on $\rho_3 \alpha_{34}$, when you don't have any $2$ on any of the other $\alpha$ terms.

Comment: Is there no upper bound on any of the variables?

Comment: Also, your calculation doesn't necessarily work, because $|x_i-1|>|x_i|$ if $x_i \in (0,1/2)$. Similarly it's possible that $|1-\sum \alpha_{ij} x_j|>1$ if $\sum \alpha_{ij} x_j>2$. If both of these occur, then the resulting minus signs cancel out, and your inequality fails.

Comment: @Ian It perplexes me too. Here is the excerpt from the paper: http://s8.postimg.org/4vd8tkw1h/inequality.png

Comment: @Ian Ah ok I see what you're saying. I'm not sure how the constants they pick correct for that though

Comment: @Brenton I see. Could it be a typo?

Comment: @Théophile That's how it was written in the paper, though I wouldn't be surprised if the paper had a typo and there should only be one $2$

Comment: Unless there's more information given on these variables, since it's symmetric in every other way, that extra 2 just about has to be a typo.

Comment: *Surely* that's a typo. I'd go ahead and try to prove it without the 2nd-to-last 2; since the $\rho$ and $\alpha$ values are all positive, that'll also prove it if you include the 2. :)